# How to sort an array of strings representing month and year?

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, swift3

I have an array of strings in my code which represents a series of months in years. Something like this:

```
let arrayOfMonths = ["May 2017", "January 2018", "August 2016", "January 2015", "June 2017"]
```

I'd like to **sort** it, by following the classic succession of months and years, so I'd like an output like this:

```
let sortedArrayOfMonths = ["January 2015", "August 2016", "May 2017", "June 2017", "January 2018"]
```

How can I do it in Swift 3? Thanks.

Comment: Convert the strings to `Date` and sort them.

Comment: I don't want a full Date object, I want to sort only strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply

```
let formatter : DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    df.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    return df
}()

let arrayOfMonths = ["May 2017", "January 2018", "August 2016", "January 2015", "June 2017"]

let sortedArrayOfMonths = arrayOfMonths.sorted( by: { formatter.date(from: $0)! < formatter.date(from: $1)! })
```

Comment: I didn't know that .dateFormat (MMMM yyyy), nice solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit more and I found the method ".sorted()" in Swift 3, so I built my working solution. I post in case someone needs:

```
let monthForNumber = ["January":1, "February":2, "March":3, "April":4, "May":5, "June":6, "July":7, "August":8, "September":9, "October":10, "November":11, "December":12]
```

For semplicity, I created the struct "Month", with "name" property and "year" property, I'll use the object month:

```
let month_1 = Month.init(name: "May", year: 2016)
let month_2 = Month.init(name: "April", year: 2010)
let month_3 = Month.init(name: "April", year: 2009)
let month_4 = Month.init(name: "January", year: 2026)
let month_5 = Month.init(name: "June", year: 2016)

let unsortedMonthsArray = [Month]()
unsortedMonthsArray.append(month_1)
unsortedMonthsArray.append(month_2)
unsortedMonthsArray.append(month_3)
unsortedMonthsArray.append(month_4)
unsortedMonthsArray.append(month_5)

let sortedArrayOfMonths = self.unsortedMonthsArray?.sorted(by: { (month1, month2) -> Bool in
        if self.monthForNumber[month1.name!] != self.monthForNumber[month2.name!] {
            if month1.year != month2.year {
                return month1.year < month2.year
            } else {
                return self.monthForNumber[month1.name!]! < self.monthForNumber[month2.name!]!
            }
        } else {
            if month1.year != month2.year {
                return month1.year < month2.year
            } else {
                return self.monthForNumber[month1.name!]! < self.monthForNumber[month2.name!]!
            }
        }
    })
```

This solution will give a sorted array of Months, that can be easily transformed into an array of strings ("monthName_monthYear").

Answer (score 0):

You could also have done this:

```
let sortedMonths  = arrayOfMonths.map{($0,$0.components(separatedBy:" "))}
                    .map{($0,$1[1]+"\(Calendar.current.monthSymbols.index(of: $1[0])!+10)")}
                    .sorted{$0.1<$1.1}
                    .map{$0.0}
```